# How big is the risk for regression in a single arm meta-analysis?

Tags: regression, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I'm performing a single arm meta-analysis of continous data deriving from efficacy evaluation   of control gorups surgical procedure. How big is the risk for regression to the mean? And How it could be evaluated? To look the design look my artiche attached, it's the same. Thanks. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22117895

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to reply despite this being an old question.

The risk of regression to the mean is always present when conducting an aggregate level meta-analysis.

However, the risk is substantial in my opinion only when trying to correlate different features at an aggregate level.

As far as I am aware, there is no specific test to evaluate it, but you can find some suggestions here:

http://digitalcommons.ilr.cornell.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1012&context=articles

https://us.sagepub.com/en-us/nam/correlation-and-regression/book17559

In any case, my pragmatic approach would be for you to proceed any way. In the worst case scenario you will inform readers of the meta-epidemiologic features of the evidence base. Whether your findings will be impactful will depend on the need for information and the competing sources of evidence.